# split a dataframe column into equal parts

Tags: python, pandas

I want to break this column into three components: city, state, zip. I was considering something like this: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html. However, I think the column needs to be a series first? Any help would be great.

```
import pandas as pd
suite_list
hospital_list =pd.DataFrame(suite_list, columns=['name', 'address_1', 'address_2', 'city_state_zip', 'phone'])
```

`city_state_zip` example = Sahuarita, AZ, 85629. I want 'Sahuarite', 'AZ,' '85629' to show up as individual columns in the DataFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : ('john','doe','smith'), 'address_1' : (105,305,505), 'address_2' : ('path','lane','route'),\
           'city_state_zip': ('Sahuarita, AZ, 85629', 'Sahuarita1, AZ1, 75629', 'Sahuarita2, AZ2, 65629')})
```

`df`

```
        Name    address_1   address_2   city_state_zip
0        john   105             path    Sahuarita, AZ, 85629
1        doe    305             lane    Sahuarita1, AZ1, 75629
2        smith  505             route   Sahuarita2, AZ2, 65629
```

and then try,

```
df["col1"],df["col2"],df["col3"] = zip(*df["city_state_zip"].str.split().tolist())
```

the output `df` will be

```
       Name address_1   address_2   city_state_zip      col1     col2     col3
    0   john    105     path    Sahuarita, AZ,85629     Sahuarita   AZ     85629
    1   doe 3   05      lane    Sahuarita1, AZ1,5629    Sahuarita1  AZ1    75629
    2   smith   505     route   Sahuarita2, AZ2,65629   Sahuarita2  AZ2    65629
```

This should give what are you looking for.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in! I think that is very close to what I want. it seems to be getting tripped up on split(' ',1). It produced a long list of what I want to split in city_state_zip if I went hospitals_complete.city_state_zip.values.tolist(). I I just want to split each now into new columns now. Does that make sense?

Comment: I still need to preserve the original columns too.

Comment: I take that back! It worked. I just needed to split on ',' vs ' ', 1 because that broke up some of longer named cities so I ended up with 4 columns instead of 3. Thanks!

Comment: @StevenGarboden sorry for late. See my updated answer! Glad to help!